# PHPmailer - CSS não aparece

Tags: php, css, html5, phpmailer

Olá, estou tentando configurar o phpmailer para enviar uma mensagem em html com css, mas ele não esta reconhecendo o css.

O que está errado?

```
$mail->Body = '
        <style type="text/css">
            .corpo {margin: 15px;padding: 15px;background-color: #FFF;}
            .body {background-color: #E1E1E1;font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;}
        </style>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="corpo">
                <p><img src="http://...../images/logoEmpresa.png" width="90" height="50"></p>
                <p>O conteúdo da nova tag div é inserido aqui</p>
            </div>
        </div>

';
```

Comment: Tem que colocar dentro das tags `<head></head>`.

Comment: @DiegoSouza Mesmo assim, não funciona.

Comment: Agora no email esta aparecendo todo o html

Comment: Como está seu cabeçalho do e-mail ? `text/html` ?

Comment: header do php ou do html?

Comment: To php esta assim `header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` no html esta como no codigo acima

Comment: E por acaso seu WebMail ou programa de correio eletrônico está configurado para ler e-mails formato HTML, Rich Text ou Text ?

Comment: Estou testando de localhost para o gmail.

Comment: No PHPMailer dá para configurar o header do e-mail. Coloque isso aí também: `$mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;"`.

Comment: Também não consegui....

Comment: Você montou o e-mail certo ? Tem que ter o Body. `<html><head><style type="text/css">
            .corpo {margin: 15px;padding: 15px;background-color: #FFF;}
            .body {background-color: #E1E1E1;font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;}
        </style></head><body> <div class="body">
            <div class="corpo">
                <p><img src="http://...../images/logoEmpresa.png" width="90" height="50"></p>
                <p>O conteúdo da nova tag div é inserido aqui</p>
            </div>
        </div></body></html>`

Comment: tamambem não da certo...rsrs

Comment: Cara vc habilitou o HTML certinho?

Comment: Tipo, fora do phpMailer funciona? Como tá o HTML quando vc recebe o e-mail?

Comment: html funciona tipo `<H1>`, mas **CSS** que não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exatamente como disse o @Fernando

Vou deixar a minha solução em colaboração, caso outros tenham a mesma dúvida:

```
<body style="margin:0px;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="50" style="background-color:#BCBCBC; margin:0px;"><tbody><tr><td height="331" valign="top">

    <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="50" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"><tbody><tr><td>
          Aqui vai seu texto
    </td></tr></tbody></table>

</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora só trabalhar sua mensagem de acordo com sua necessidade.

Answer (score 3):

Bom seu problema não tem relação qualquer problema com PHP ou com o PHPmailer, mas sim que, `style CSS` não funciona para todos os provedores de e-mail.

Em seu caso o destino é o gmail e este remove todos os `<head>`, `<style>` de seu e-mail.

Então a unica solução para criar e-mail estilizados com CSS, que funcionem na grande maioria dos provedores de e-mail é partindo para o CSS *inline*, há até algumas ferramentas para isso (converte style CSS em CSS inline), como [CSS Inliner Tool](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/), [Inliner](http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php), [Inline styler](https://inlinestyler.torchbox.com/).

[Está fonte](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/css-in-html-email) cita além do CSS *inline*, outras técnicas para que seu e-mail seja interpretado de forma adequada pela maior parte dos provedores. Como:

- **Mantenha o seu código simples:** Codificação para HTML e-mail é diferente da codificação para website. Quanto mais simples o código, menos espaço para erros.
- **Use somente CSS para elementos de estilo gerais:** Você vai obter os melhores resultados se você usar CSS para elementos gerais, como fontes ou cores.
- **Use CSS inline (em linha):** Aplicativos de e-mail baseados em navegador, como o Gmail, tiram as tags `<head>` e `<body>` por padrão.

> Outra dica, que não está na fonte citada, crie o layout de seu email dentro de tabelas (`<table>`), não economize tabelas, crie tabelas dentro de células de tabela, esqueça [Tableless](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless), na hora de criar e-mails. Alguns provedores (Outlook Desktop e Outlook webmail) adoram não respeitar os estilos de seu lindo layout com divs. (Recentemente tive que refatorar um layout completo para tabelas `=(`).